# Compare a value and increment the value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a value in textbox as '203' in that '0' should be increment every time as [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,.......Z] so next increment value should be '213,223,233,243,253,263,273,283,293,2A3,2B3,2C3,2D3,2E3....'

So I created a dropdown box 'revision' where the values as[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,.......Z]

using sustr I strip the '0' position and I got value in variable 'value1'.

```
var value1=item.substr(0,1)
var arr = document.getElementsByName('revision')
var x = arr[0].selectedIndex
```

How do I compare the `value1` in `arr[0].length` and increment to next as of dropdown data?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3a8Lx/ ?

Comment: Does it make any sense at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function createOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("revision");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9 ; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    } 
    for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = String.fromCharCode(i);
        opt.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(i);
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
createOption();
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    currentIndex ++;
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
    var select = document.getElementById("revision");
    var lastChar = txt.value.substr(txt.value.length - 1, 1);
    var firstChar = txt.value.substr(0, 1);
    select.value =  select.childNodes[currentIndex].value;
    txt.value = firstChar + select.childNodes[currentIndex].value + lastChar;
};
```

Here's [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/7U72M/1/)

Comment: actually there is 1 button on click that button it should increment .I m not try to change 'revision' dropdown it should automatically take next index value and gets concatenate with the fisrtchar+next index value+last char.

Comment: It is showing error in select.appendChild(opt); Im facing error message as.., null is null or not an object. kindly help me.

Comment: Did you call var opt = document.createElement("option");? This function create "options" elements.

Comment: Yes i added your code..still same error. But my doubt is where you checking the current value for instance current value is 203 in that value is 0 and need to increment to next index value in dropdown that is 1 so 213 next time it should be next index value that is 2 so 223...

Comment: Can you give me your current webpage in order to I can see what's going on with your solution? You can put your code on JSFIDDLE or mail to me hicurin@gmail.com.